# My Y axis doesnt show all the dates on Y axis while plotting heatmap in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I know how to make a good heatmap in seaborn, but I would like to use the Plotly package. I used the code below, but my Y axis doesn't show all the dates, how can I show all the the dates on my y axis?

I want background color be white and each category have different custom color too, how should I modify the code?

My data frames includes a date column and other columns which I would put them on X axis

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.imshow(df, text_auto=True,color_continuous_scale='RdBu_r', origin='lower')


fig.show()
```

[image]

What I want is the following:

[image]

A sample of my data frame:

```
            a   b   c   d   e   f
DATE                        
2010-04-12  0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Chart based on code provided as below:
[image]

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#using-tickformat-attribute--datetime - maybe this is it?

Comment: No it doesnt help

Comment: I could solve this if you would `matplotlib` instead of `plotly`, but this would be more than ten of lines of code...

Comment: Yes I can not use matplotlib , because I am building streamlit app and for some reason, it doesnt install it on python 3.7. and I tried all the ways. it has problem with seaborn and matplotlib, it has no issue on jupyter but when I want to build a docker image, it doesnt install this two

Comment: I am open to bokeh as well, if it is easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ticks can be changed to any desired value by manually updating the layout.
To show all the dates and avoid being automatically compressed by Plotly, you can pass the dates to yaxis as string.

Regarding the background color, it is controlled by the color scale. Set `color_continuous_scale` as `blues` will probably give you a white background.

```py
fig = px.imshow(df.values, color_continuous_scale='blues',
                aspect='auto', width=500, height=600)
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = np.arange(len(df)),
        ticktext = df.index.astype(str)
    ),
    xaxis = dict(visible = False)
)
fig.show()
```

[image: result image]

If the heat map is too long to show all the dates, just skip some of them.

```py
fig = px.imshow(df_long.values, color_continuous_scale='blues',
                aspect='auto', width=500, height=600)
n_skip = 10
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = np.arange(0, len(df_long), n_skip), # skip here
        ticktext = df_long.index.astype(str)[::n_skip] # skip here
    ),
    xaxis = dict(
        tickvals = np.arange(df_long.shape[1]),
        ticktext = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    )
)
fig.update_coloraxes(showscale=False)  # remove color bar
fig.show()
```

[image: result image long without color bar]

Comment: Thank you, this is my shape of data ((3695, 6), when I run the code, jupyter stop working, maybe because the data is too large? what if I we show most of date but not all? because it seems it is not possible, I have also 317 unique date

Comment: I have updated the answer to accommodate to long data by skipping some of the dates.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I add the name each feature  on below? and remove also the column beside heatmap, is there a a way that we color each of segment of this heat map with different color?

Comment: You can modify xaxis in the same way for yaxis. Just pass all the column names you want as ticktext. To remove color bar, use `fig.update_coloraxes(showscale=False)`.  However, assigning different color to each segment, AFAIK it's impossible in Plotly.

Comment: I added the plot the plot that I used your code, the issue is, there is some duplicate date ..

Comment: how can we avoid duplicate date?

Comment: Duplicated dates can be manually substituted by blank spaces before you pass the date list to the `ticktext`.

Comment: I think the best possible solution to this huge data and duplicates (which I also would like to show ) is that I can create heatmap for each year.. like year if I select like in a check box yesr 2016, it shows me heatmap relevant to it

Comment: Can you help me on that?

Comment: Extended discussions in comments is not encouraged by stackoverflow. Please consider open up a new post if you need help with new problems, such as adding a check box, as they do not directly relate to the original problem.